# User authenticating by email address with auth_key

Tags: php, email, authentication, yii2

i try to send email after registration with authkey attribute. But i have problem with this authkey from user. I dont know why it not save this before send this email. There is my code from SignupForm:

```
 public function getSetPasswordLink() {
       $user = User::findOne([
                    'status' => User::STATUS_DELETED,
                    'email' => $this->email,

        ]);
        var_dump($user['auth_key']);
        exit();
        return Url::to(['registration/confirm', 'email' => $this->email, 'authkey' => $user['auth_key']], true);
    }

    public function sendEmail() {

        $status = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('registrationmail',['url' => $this->getSetPasswordLink()])
                ->setTo($this->email)
                ->setCharset('utf8')
                ->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => \Yii::$app->params['supportEmail']])
                ->setSubject(self::SUBJECT)
                ->send();

        return $status;
    }
```

There is my function sendEmail with url which i try to pass to the view. This var_dum return me NUll. MAybe i show my action Confirm in my RegistrationController:

```
public function actionConfirm($email, $key) {

        $user = \common\models\User::find()->where([
                    'email' => $email,
                    'auth_key' => $key,
                    'status' => 0,
                ])->one();
        if (!empty($user)) {
            $user->status = 10;
            $user->save();
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', 'Success!');
        } else {
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('warning', 'Failed!');
        }
        return $this->goHome();
    }
```

So i send email and in this email i pass url to my actionConfirm. If user click this link his status become 1 instead of 0. But I dont know why my auth_key is return me NULL. Anyone can see my fail?

Answer (score 0):

in your getSetPasswordLink 
your code exit before return .. the auth_key link ...

```
   var_dump($user['auth_key']);
    exit();
    return Url::to(['registration/confirm', 'email' => $this->email, 'authkey' => $user['auth_key']], true);
```

in this way your sendEmail() can't get the right value to send  ..

Comment: i know about that but if i remove varump with exit it not work

Comment: my link look like: http://mypage/index.php?r=registration%2Fconfirm&email=(my email)%40gmail.com but there is without auth_key and when i click link i render my page with Bad Request (#400)
Missing required parameters: key

Comment: so this auth_key is Null

Comment: ..  i  think that  if you remove exit() ,   then the function should return the url .. with the  auth_key ... but if the auth_key is null before this return ..and you can see null in var_dump(..) that mean you have not saved a valida auth_key User ... entry .. please  ... confirm or not this ..

Comment: i solved it just i setn my email before i save user data in my function save